# Mouseover with jQuery, too fast with the mouse

Tags: jquery

I get an issue using "mouseover" function with jQuery.

When I'm too fast with the mouse on my element I lose the "mouseleave" function and my element don't delete himself...

My JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tonymx227/4YRuf/5/

My code :

```
$('figure').children('img').on('mouseover', function(e){
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="figure-over"><a href="'+$(this).parent().data('url')+'" target="_blank">Voir</a></div>');
    $(this).parent().children('#figure-over').stop().slideDown();
    $(this).parent().children('#figure-over').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).stop().slideUp( function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }).on('click', function(){
        window.open($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Comment: You are connecting one event inside the other for starters, which leads to multiple callbacks... that will cause problems. Connect the mouseleave outside the mouseover event - use the deferred syntax of `on` if the objects are transient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :   http://jsfiddle.net/4YRuf/13/

With this : You can quickly move your mouse and the result is much better.
And use of class instead of id...

```
$('figure').children('img').on('mouseover', function(e){
    $('.figure-over').remove();
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="figure-over"><a href="'+$(this).parent().data('url')+'" target="_blank">Voir</a></div>');
    $(this).parent().children('.figure-over').stop().slideDown();
    $(this).on('mouseleave', removeIt)
    $(this).parent().children('.figure-over').on('mouseleave', removeIt).on('click', function(){
        window.open($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
    });
});


function removeIt()
{    
    if( ! $('.figure-over').is(':hover') )
    {

        $('.figure-over').stop().slideUp( function(){

                $(this).remove();
            });
    }
}
```

UPDATE :

works better with : http://jsfiddle.net/4YRuf/17/

```
$('figure').children('img').on('mouseover', function(e){

    if ( $('.figure-over').length == 0)
    {
         $(this).parent().append('<div class="figure-over"><a href="'+$(this).parent().data('url')+'" target="_blank">Voir</a></div>');   
    }

    $(this).parent().children('.figure-over').stop().slideDown();
    $(this).on('mouseleave', removeIt)
    $(this).parent().children('.figure-over').on('mouseleave', removeIt).on('click', function(){
        window.open($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
    });
});


function removeIt()
{    
    if( ! $('.figure-over').is(':hover') )
    {

        $('.figure-over').stop().slideUp( function(){

                $(this).remove();
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: oups, i come back in 5 min, so , sorry

Comment: Not bad, but it flickers a lot if you move in and out fast.

Comment: I guess he does not mind the flickering :) Well done.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, amazing 'post'... Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (I switched to using `mouseout`):

### http://jsfiddle.net/4YRuf/14/

```
$('figure').children('img').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).parent().find('#figure-over').length){
        $(this).parent().append('<div id="figure-over"><a href="' + $(this).parent().data('url') + '" target="_blank">Voir</a></div>');
        $(this).parent().children('#figure-over').slideDown();
    }
});
$(document).on('mouseout', '#figure-over', function () {
    $(this).stop().slideUp(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}).on('click', '#figure-over', function () {
    window.open($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
});
```

basically assume your mouseenter events will occur repeatedly and check before adding the child objects again. You also need to connect to the leave events outside the enter event to avoid accidentally chaining multiple events - although the contains check would avoid this too. e.g.

```
$('figure').children('img').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).parent().find('#figure-over').length){
        $(this).parent().append('<div id="figure-over"><a href="' + $(this).parent().data('url') + '" target="_blank">Voir</a></div>');
        $(this).parent().children('#figure-over').stop().slideDown();
        $(this).parent().children('#figure-over').on('mouseoutfunction () {
            $(this).stop().slideUp(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }).on('click', function () {
            window.open($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Le_Morri: What problem is that? Please be specific as I am unable to reproduce the original problem by moving mouse fast on this example.

Comment: If you move the mouse fast in and out the `mouseleave` is not triggered => The overlay doesn't hide

Comment: Yes, the same problem... When you try to move fast in and out the new element, you lose the mouseleave...

Comment: Mouseout is more effective in this case - try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/4YRuf/14/

Comment: Yes much better... but when you move fast on the image, for example in the left bottom on the image, the new element don't delete himself... Yes multiple instances...